# troubleshooting AngularJS directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

i've declared a template and controller as per documentation, and have a basic semi-working example

index.html & view :

```
index.html
<script src="scripts/FileUpload/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>

MyView.html
<div data-ng-controller="uploader">
     <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
     <button ng-click="foo()">foo</button>
</div>
```

app / controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularFileUpload'])  // ng-file-upload

angular.module('app').controller('uploader', ['common', '$scope', '$http', '$upload', uploader]);

function uploader(common, $scope, $http, $upload) {
...
    $scope.foo = function () {
        log('bar..');
    };
    $scope.fileUploadObj = "TestString";
    $scope.onFilesSelect = function ($files) {
        log('files selected!');
        ...
    }
```

I added function foo to ensure that my controller is bound, and that works. However **onFileSelect never gets triggered and i don't see any errors**.

looking at Angular.js **Batarang** profiler, i see the following for the scope in question.

```
Models for (007)
{ 
    foo: null
    fileUploadObj: TestString
    onFilesSelect: null
}
```

both functions show as null, but i know *foo* is wired.

so my question would be, how do i troubleshoot where the disconnect happens for onFileSelect($files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)"
```

vs

```
$scope.onFilesSelect
```

one has an ***s*** in File

Comment: wow.. cant believe this.. Actually initially i had handlers for single and multiple files (both on the view and controller), and none of them worked. so i narrowed it down to simplest case, and overlooked this small detail :) .. and not sure what i did but it does indeed work now after correcting the name, thanks.

Comment: happens to the best of us